# How to display image which is stored on s3 without storing on harddisk?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, attachment-fu

In my rails app I have used attachment_fu to upload images and stored it on s3.
I want to display these images on browser without retrieving it.
How can I display images by giving s3 path?

Thanks,
Jayashri

Comment: Do you mean as an administrative function? Or do you mean have users be able to view the file directly from s3?

Comment: Yes, I want users be able to view the file directly from s3.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You just need to link to the correct S3 path for you images.

For public files they are in the format:

```
eg http://s3.amazonaws.com/[bucket]/[key]
```

If your content is [private](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/index.html?UsingAuthAccess.html) you'll need to create a [signed url](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/index.html?S3_QSAuth.html) but all the SDKs and libraries make this easy.

Then use the url to display the images:

```
<img src="http://s3.amazonaws.com/mybucket/myfile.jpg"  ... ></img>
```

Answer (score 0):

It may help you to install the S3 organizer in Firefox so you can browser your directories. Then I believe the URL's are structured kinda like this...

http://BUCKET.s3.amazonaws.com/FOO/BAR.png